# Azure email test harness

Tags: azure, testing, integration-testing

I have sites hosted in `Azure` for development and testing.

Is there some way I can point these sites to a mail server that captures and displays emails - without an additional relay?

e.g. I want to demonstrate that emails have been sent to multiple recipients without worrying that I've spammed real users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not strictly Azure-related you could use Mailtrap.io (http://mailtrap.io/).